# How to load about.html in home.html with Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am creating my website in Ionic. I have created different pages - **about.html, services.html, contact.html, products.html**.

I want to call `about.html` , `services.html` inside `home.html`. How do I do it?

I mean to show the data of `about.html` below the date of `home.html` in **home.html**.

`home.ts`

```
<ion-header >
  <ion-navbar color="danger">
    <ion-title>
      Ionic
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will be your guide.
  </p>
  <page-about></page-about>
  <page-services></page-services>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of routes.

Have the following inside your home.html

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li> <a [routerLink]="['/']" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a [routerLink]="['/about']" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="/services" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" >services</a></li>

 </ul>
```

and configure the router as,

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent }  from './components/pages/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/pages/about.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './components/pages/about.component';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path:'',
        component:HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path:'about',
        component:AboutComponent
    },
    {
        path:'services',
        component:servicesComponent
    }
];
```

**EDIT**

If you need to show the data of different components, just use the selectors of the component

```
<app-about>
<app-services>
```

Comment: i think you got it wrong, i mean to show the data of about.html below the date of home.html in home.html

Comment: in `about.ts` , selector is ` selector: `page-about` , so i added `<page-about></page-about>` in `home.html`  but getting error- 1. If 'page-about' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'page-about' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: you need to add the component inside your app.module.ts

Comment: i have added `services` page after about,  it is showing about page's data  but it is not showing `services` page , there is no error, i have added in module.ts , component.ts , updating question to show my `home.html`

Comment: make sure your service page has data independently

Comment: `<ion-content>
  <p>This is services</p>
</ion-content>`    this is services.html , is it ok ?

Comment: If i am putting services above about then i can see only services, which means i am unable to see the second one